# Is there any examples of how to implement full-screen advertisement for android?

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

Is there any examples of how to implement full-screen advertisement for android using AdMob?

I have researched and found these tutorials:

- [Getting Started with House Ads](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?query=Interstitial%20&answer=1619751)
- [Google AdMob Ads Android Advanced](http://code.google.com/intl/no-NO/mobile/ads/docs/android/advanced.html)

**EDIT - added some related questions:**

1. In the tutorials it looks like you have to use Android 4.0 to get the interstitial house ads to work. Is it not possible in earlier versions?

Comment: +1 Excellent question there Mr. JT :D I was actually wondering the same thing!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please see the AdMob Interstitial [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial) for how to add interstitials to your Android app.  Please note, however, that you need to be whitelisted for interstitial ads to get interstitial ads from AdMob.  Right now you will only be able to see the test interstitial ad, or a house ad interstitial that you traffic to your app.

EDIT:

The Google AdMob SDK v4.3.1 requires that you set your android build target to android-13 (Android 3.2) or higher.  You can still get ads on devices all the way down to Android 1.5 (android-3) by setting the minSdkVersion="3" in your manifest.

Comment: Do you know how to make a house ad? And how to become eligible? "Note: All publishers can run rich Interstitial House Ads in their own applications. Paid interstitial ads, however, are only offered to a select group of publishers. If you become eligible, Google will be sure to contact you."

Comment: Google has to contact you for you to be added for paid interstitial ads.  Your best bet is to try and create a killer app before worrying about getting these ads.  To create house ads, go to www.admob.com login, and go to sites & apps -> House ads.  Create a house ad campaign and set up an interstitial ad.

Comment: Please correct link given link no longer available.